# Unable to query remote system and change registry

Tags: vbscript

I am in need of a way to change the Java NextGen Plugin. I need to check the OS before hand so that it goes to the correct path.
I have a script that checks the OS and I have checked and rechecked it and it does work

```
On Error Resume Next

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

set objShell = wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")

strComputer = InputBox("Enter PC name:", "JavaNextGen Disable")
strVersion = InputBox("Enter Java Version:", "JavaNextGen Disable")
If ((strComputer <> "") And (strVersion <> "")) Then
 Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
 Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
 For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
  If objOperatingSystem.Caption = "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise" Then
   wscript.echo strComputer & "Is Windows 7"
  Elseif  objOperatingSystem.Caption = "Microsoft Windows XP Professional" Then
   wscript.echo strComputer & "Is Windows XP"
  End If
```

Now Here is the code That I use to change the registry setting

```
   Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
   strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in\1.6.0_" & strVersion
   strEntryName = "UseNewJavaPlugin"
   dwValue = 0
   objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strEntryName, dwValue
wscript.echo strKeyPath
   If Not Err.Number = 0 Then 
    wscript.Echo "Error: "& vbCrLf & strComputer & "Please check to make sure the computer is on the network!  And that you have admin rights on the computer!"
   Else
    wscript.echo strComputer & "NextGen has been turned off."
   End If
```

Now if I put them together it looks like this

```
On Error Resume Next
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

set objShell = wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")

strComputer = InputBox("Enter PC name:", "JavaNextGen Disable")
strVersion = InputBox("Enter Java Version:", "JavaNextGen Disable")
If ((strComputer <> "") And (strVersion <> "")) Then
 Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
 Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
 Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
 For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
  If objOperatingSystem.Caption = "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise" Then
   strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in\1.6.0_" & strVersion
   strEntryName = "UseNewJavaPlugin"
   dwValue = 0
   objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strEntryName, dwValue

   If Not Err.Number = 0 Then 
    wscript.Echo "Error: "& vbCrLf & strComputer & "Please check to make sure the computer is on the network!  And that you have admin rights on the computer!"
   Else
    wscript.echo strComputer & "NextGen has been turned off."
   End If
  Elseif  objOperatingSystem.Caption = "Microsoft Windows XP Professional" Then
   Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
   strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in\1.6.0_" & strVersion
   strEntryName = "UseNewJavaPlugin"
   dwValue = 0
   objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strEntryName, dwValue

   If Not Err.Number = 0 Then 
    wscript.Echo "Error: "& vbCrLf & strComputer & "Please check to make sure the computer is on the network!  And that you have admin rights on the computer!"
   Else
    wscript.echo strComputer & "NextGen has been turned off."
   End If
  End If
 Next
End If
```

However it doesn't do anything after this line, I know due to adding an echo just after that and I don't get anything on my screen.
      If objOperatingSystem.Caption = "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise" Then

Comment: I was able to get it fixed by doing a trim()
changed 
If objOperatingSystem.Caption = "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise" Then
to
If trim(objOperatingSystem.Caption) = "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise" Then
also did it for the XP one.

Comment: Great job finding and fixing your code! Could you create an Answer below with the solution you created, and mark it as the Answer by clicking the checkmark next to the new answer? This would help others in your situation, by seeing there's a accepted answer. :)